# package install location via RStudio vs location via Rstats

Tags: r

`Windows 10` here.

When I install a package via `R`, it is installed in the location:

`C:\Users\user.name\Desktop\portableLarge\statistics\Rstats-Portable\R-Portable\App\R-Portable\library`

When I install a package via `RStudio` (which uses the abovementioned `R`), I get this message (using package `datasauRus` as an example):

```
package ‘datasauRus’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\user.name\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpa8DjxM\downloaded_packages
```

What is `RStudio` trying to tell me? Why won't it install the packages in the same location `R` uses?

Comment: It is installed in the library location. What R tries to say is that it first downloaded the binary file in a random location (you see that it has a random name like `Rtmpa8DjxM`. Then it goes to the library location.

Comment: @Manu Thanks. Did you mean "R tries to say" or "RStudio tries to say"?

Comment: I meant R tries to say, because RStudio only acts as IDE.